# how to generate multiple text fields based on a GET api and post it back

Tags: flutter

I have an endpoint that returns a list of questions. Each question has the following properties

1. Input field name eg: Select from the following list
2. Validation eg: IsRequired
3. controlType eg: (dropdown, text, image, file)
4. values eg (dart, javascript, python)

I want to build input forms on the fly on mobile when i get this endpoint. How do i go about this on flutter. I already have the api.

Think of it like a quiz app but with different controls. eg. dropdown, textfield, checkbox.

Here is an example of the api response

```js
[
 {
    "question": "what is your name ?",
    "cotrollType": "textField",
    "values": [],
    "validations": [
      {
        "validation": "IsRequired"
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    "question": "select from the dropdown:",
    "cotrollType": "dropdown",
    "values": ["one", "two", "three"],
    "validations": [
      {
        "validation": "IsRequired"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please post the response of the api

Comment: hope this makes things a bit more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

yeah more code is needed but probably you could just use BloC to get the API response and create the Widgets there and then just emit them as new state, that way you can show some sort of progress indidcator in the meantime, also are you using some kind of model to parse the response and make it a bit easier?